# strtotime() doesn't return unix timestamp in custom view when $row->field_date is an English date

Tags: views, datetime

I'm confused. I'm using a Global: PHP field inside a view to tweak the output of the row based on the date value of a certain field.

```
print (strtotime((string)$row->field_date));
```

Doesn't seem to return anything.

```
print $row->field_date;
```

Returns "Tuesday, December 1, 2015"

```
print strtotime('Tuesday, December 1, 2015');
```

Returns 1448956800

I've tried converting the $row object to an array just for fun with `get_object_vars($row)` but that didn't work either.

In my case I expect that `print (strtotime((string)$row->field_date));` returns the value (unix timestamp) 1448956800.

Comment: and the desired output is?

Comment: I'd expect `print (strtotime((string)$row->field_date));` to print a unix timestamp like 1448956800. That is what I desire.

Answer (score 1):

`$row->field_date` contains markup, not just the date/string value hence strtotime() won't/can't return a valid unix timestamp. To fix, try using strip_tags() around the returned value of `$row->field_date` like:

```
strtotime(strip_tags((string)$row->field_date));
```

or use "Strip HTML tags" option checkbox under "Rewrite Results" in the "Configure field" dialog.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/69489)

Comment: @digital Have another look, this does appear to answer the question

Comment: I've added more detail. I did feel that I was clearly answering the question.